# Decrease of $(1/\zeta)^{(r)}(\sigma + i T)$ as $\sigma\to -\infty$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

What is a standard reference for the simple fact that, for $T$ fixed and $\sigma\to -\infty$,
every derivative $|(1/\zeta)^{(r)}(\sigma+i T)|$ of the Riemann zeta function decreases faster than any exponential on $\sigma$?

Here is a quick sketch of a proof: use the functional equation
$\zeta(s) = \zeta(1-s) 2^s \pi^{s-1} \Gamma(1-s) \sin \frac{\pi s}{2}$,
together with the fact that any derivative $(1/\Gamma)^{(j)}(\sigma+iT)$ decreases
faster than any exponential for $T$ fixed and $\sigma\to \infty$. In turn,
this fact about $(1/\Gamma)^{(j)}(\sigma+iT)$ follows easily from the following: for $T$ fixed, $\Gamma(\sigma+iT)$ grows
faster than any exponential as $\sigma\to \infty$ (by Stirling's formula),
whereas, again for $T$ fixed and $\sigma\to \infty$,
$(\Gamma'/\Gamma)(\sigma+i T)$ is bounded by $O(\log \sigma)$
and every derivative of $(\Gamma'/\Gamma)$ is $O(1)$ (see, e.g., appendix C.1 in Montgomery-Vaughan).

Comment: You can reduce the statement to $r=0$ by applying Cauchy's formula for derivatives. Of course you need to assume that $T\neq 0$ otherwise the trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ invalidate the statement.

Comment: ,Ah, and then it's just the functional equation, together with the fact that $\Gamma(\sigma+iT)$ grows taster than any exponential as $\sigma\to \infty$.